# Problems uploading a mercurial repository to github using hg-git

Tags: git, github, mercurial, hg-git

I have hg-git installed, and a mercurial repository, and I want to upload it to github. I've created a project and am in the "quick setup" phase where I get URIs I can use:

```
https://github.com/eyalroz/usdt-ontime.git
git@github.com:eyalroz/usdt-ontime.git
```

So, the first thing I tried is editing `.hg/hgrc` in my mercurial repository and adding

```
[paths]
default = git+ssh://git@github.com/eyalroz/usdt-ontime.git
```

and added a master bookmark:

```
hg bookmark -r default master # so a ref gets created
```

as per the instructions [here](https://hg-git.github.io/). Then I tried to push, and failed:

```
$ hg push
pushing to git+ssh://git@github.com/eyalroz/usdt-ontime.git
abort: repository git+ssh://git@github.com/eyalroz/usdt-ontime.git not found!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems your `.hgrc` file should contain:

```
[extensions]
hgext.bookmarks =
hggit =
```

(which probably enables these two and sets them to their default value) for hg-git functionality to actually work.